# Java: Composition of classes implementing same interface

Tags: java, interfaces, composition

Let's consider an example wherein I have to model the following:

1. Class to schedule exams for a Student, lets call it `StudentExamScheduler`
2. Class to schedule exam for a Class. Let's call it `ClassExamScheduler` and currently it depends on the logic provided by `StudentExamScheduler`.

So since both the classes schedule exams, I created an interface `ExamScheduler` which both the classes would implement. Reason being:

- They are essentially scheduling exams
- would give me the flexibility to swap the schedulers in-and-out as functionality changes.

This is how the interface would look:

```
interface ExamScheduler {
       scheduleExam(data);
}
```

Now each of my concrete class implements this interface and `ClassExamScheduler` now uses the `StudentExamScheduler` to delegate some responsibilities.

```
class ClassExamScheduler implements ExamScheduler {

  private ExamScheduler studentExamScheduler;

  public scheduleExam() {

    studentExamScheduler.scheduleExam();
    // do other stuff
  }
}
```

Is this a valid use of Interface & Composition? Typically I have seen Interface being used for polymorphism. But in this use case I use it to provide me flexibility to inject new classes when the requirements change.

Comment: What you have written here is an example of the Decorator design pattern, one of the most common uses of composition and polymorphism.  There's certainly nothing wrong with this approach.

Comment: @Jules yeah it looks like a variant of decorator without any inheritance stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**My two cents:**

- There's no contradiction between the use of interfaces and composition.
- You are using polymorphism. Dependency injection and delegation are possible because of polymorphism.

**A couple of observations:**

- The `studentExamScheduler` should be named `examScheduler`. Since you will be injecting it you should not name the variable after an specific implementos of `ExamScheduler`.
- Consider creating a more generic `Scheduler` interface, with a schedule(ScheduleData data); such an interface could be implemented by any type of scheduler like `LessonScheduler`, `MeetingScheduler` etc.

Comment: My bad, I just tried to come up with a simple example of the problem I am trying to solve. Added the implements clause.

Comment: @AgentX I deleted that observation and changed it for another one related to a more generic interface.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. I have tried to keep the interface generic in regards with the Business Process at hand.

Answer (score 2):

Using interfaces like this is usually an easy and clean way to provide flexibility. For example you could change the implementation of a `ClassExamScheduler` instance at runtime without modifying source code. This is possible by assigning `studentExamScheduler` another type of `ExamScheduler` that provide some other method of scheduling. This kind of **polymorphism** is one of the main benefits of using interfaces.

**However**

I don't see any real benefits of having `ClassExamScheduler` implement `ExamScheduler`. I see where you are going with the aspect of composition; since both classes schedule exams, they could implement a common method.

But this means that a `ClassExamScheduler` can implement it's `.scheduleExam(..)`-method by using another `ClassExamScheduler` instance as a middleman, which to me seems kind of odd and unnecessarily complicated.

Second, this structure could cause **program failure** if used without caution. If a `ClassExamScheduler` would implement a closed chain of `ClassExamSchedulers` like:

```
ClassExamScheduler A, B, C;
A.studentExamScheduler = B;
B.studentExamScheduler = C;
C.studentExamScheduler = A;
```

Or even itself:

```
ClassExamScheduler A;
A.studentExamScheduler = A;
```

You would end up with a **recursive loop** that would end in a stack overflow.

**Regarding composition**

I think that the subtle distinction here is that `StudentExamScheduler` schedules an exam and `ClassExamScheduler` *uses* an `ExamScheduler` (i.e. an `StudentExamScheduler`) to schedule an exam, *indirectly*.

Comment: I don't think that I understand your answer completely. In the Business Problem I am trying to solve, these `StudentExamScheduler` and `ClassExamScheduler` are a bit different. `ClassExamScheduler` currently needs a specific way of scheduling student's exams, the functionality is provided by `StudentExamScheduler`. Now `StudentExamScheduler` currently depends on specific framework which might change tomorrow. So using this approach I would get the flexibility that you mentioned.

Comment: Is there something specific in my answer that you want me to make clear? My main point was that `ClassExamScheduler` won't have to implement `ExamScheduler` to achieve your desired functionality. Rather, making `ClassExamScheduler` implement `ExamScheduler` introduces risks of misuse since a `ClassExamScheduler` could provide this functionality, i.e. an instance of `ClassExamScheduler` could be your `private ExamScheduler studentExamScheduler;`. To utilize the interface you'd instead want to have different classes for different frameworks instead of changing `StudentExamScheduler` every time.